# Trying to use a select query after two with statements

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

I plan to make two with queries that make two temporary tables, one which gives the sum of the remaining loan payments, and one that gives the sum of all the transactions in the table. I've tested the two with statements and they work by themselves, however trying to perform a select query with them only seems to return errors.

```
WITH RemainingLoans AS(SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, l.NextPayment, l.FullPaymentConfirmed) * l.MonthlyPaymentRate) AS RemainingPayments FROM loans AS l);
WITH CurrentBalances AS(SELECT SUM(t.amount) AS allBalances FROM transactions AS t);
SELECT l.RemainingPayments - b.allBalances AS TotalOutstandings FROM RemainingLoans AS l, CurrentBalances AS b;
```

The first with is called RemainingLoans with one attribute RemainingPayments, and the second with is called CurrentBalances with one attribute allBalances. To my knowledge these should work like tables which is why I attempted my select clause on the third line, however I am currently getting syntax errors. Is there a correct way to format my select statement?

Comment: What exact version of MySQL are you using?  `SELECT version();`  and what is the exact error?   Add both details to the question.

Comment: WITH list elements are separated by a comma.  There's only one `WITH` keyword at the beginning of the list.  The semicolon goes at the end of the entire statement, not after the `WITH` list elements.

Comment: Something like this: `WITH RemainingLoans AS(SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, l.NextPayment, l.FullPaymentConfirmed) * l.MonthlyPaymentRate) AS RemainingPayments FROM loans AS l)
   , CurrentBalances AS(SELECT SUM(t.amount) AS allBalances FROM transactions AS t)
SELECT l.RemainingPayments - b.allBalances AS TotalOutstandings FROM RemainingLoans AS l, CurrentBalances AS b
;`

Comment: Thank you, that solved the issue completely.

Comment: @JonArmstrong That should be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a single statement, not multiple statements.

[The fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1435eacaaa2fe893872f451f23752b06)

`WITH` list elements are separated by a comma. There's only one `WITH` keyword at the beginning of the list.

The semicolon goes at the end of the entire statement, not after the `WITH` list elements.

Here's the adjusted statement:

```sql
WITH RemainingLoans AS (
       SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, l.NextPayment, l.FullPaymentConfirmed) * l.MonthlyPaymentRate) AS RemainingPayments
         FROM loans AS l
     )
   , CurrentBalances AS (
       SELECT SUM(t.amount) AS allBalances
         FROM transactions AS t
     )
SELECT l.RemainingPayments - b.allBalances AS TotalOutstandings
  FROM RemainingLoans  AS l
     , CurrentBalances AS b
;
```